# 144 Hz IPS monitor which pass Lagom.nl Sharpness test

Tags: monitors

I'm looking for a high refresh rate IPS monitor. It should have no problems with text clarity, because it will be used not only for gaming/entertainment, but for web browsing and reading also. This test helps to check if the monitor has correct sharpness and does not apply any artificial blurring or sharpening filters, which may make fonts look worse: http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/sharpness.php

I've already done a small research about some other models, and it turns out they fail the test: see this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monitors/comments/6sojee/any_120_hz_ips_monitors_which_pass_lagomnl/) for details.

If you're going to test your monitor, it's essential for Lagom test image to display 1:1, so make sure DPI scaling in OS, and zoom in web browser are set to 100%, and nothing in the system scales/resizes the picture or applies some artificial blur/sharpening filter.

It would be interesting to know if ASUS PG279Q, AOC AG271QG, LG 34UC79G or any other model with similar specs pass or fail the test.

Comment: It would be hard to answer your question on the basis that a minority of people have this top end range of monitors, and a smaller percentage come onto this site. I'm not sure that manufacturers would actually provide this specific information either.